# C++ Using projects instead of libs

Tags: c++, windows, linker

I have a huge solution in VS2010 that includes several projects.
I am basically working with one of these projects.
This project needs the other projects.
However, they are currently linked with this one project only by Properties->Linker->Input.
These Input dependencies are filled by project1.lib, project2.lib, etc.

Does anybody know how I can make my project use the actual projects instead of their libs?

I am asking because I want to strip down the code, and if I remove something from the other projects, I would still have to generate the libs to actually see the changes.

That is why I would like to link directly to the other projects so that any changes are "visible" immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Project references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ez524kew%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
Project properties->Common Properties->References